# Query array from Parse.com to array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to query an array from Parse.com to an empty array.

My empty array:

```
var commentsArray = [NSArray]()
```

My query code:

```
var query1 = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
        query1.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "ImxZwVx7L8")
        query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {

                        //For each object in the class object, append it to myArray
                        if let dataArray = object["comments"] as? NSArray {
                            self.commentsArray.append(dataArray)

                            println("codeBelow")
                            println(self.commentsArray)
                            println(self.commentsArray.count)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("\(error?.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

In the output I get this:

```
codeBelow
[(
    abc,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    def,
    tdrthdrthdrthdrthdrhtrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrth,
    "jdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrthdrt dhrt hdrthdrthdrthdrh 5hsr5d r5hdr5h drthr t hdrt hkl"
)]
1
```

As you can see, the output count gives me 1, but it should give 38. If I do `println(dataArray.count)` it gives me output 38. How come? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an empty array:

```
var commentsArray: [String] = [String]()
```

Now query:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"currentUploads")
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:"ImxZwVx7L8")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        var list: AnyObject? = object.objectForKey("comments")
                        self.commentsArray = list! as! NSArray as! [String]
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                }
            } else {
                println("\(error?.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```